# Is there a way to "Inherit" a controller's prefix in Symfony 2?

Tags: php, symfony

Is there any way to for one controller to inherit another controller's routing prefix in Symfony2?

I'd like to create an "admin" route and controller that other controllers can inherit the base prefix from, e.g. The admin class would start something like this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/admin")
 */
class AdminController {...}
```

And then another class could then "inherit" only the prefix and add to it with its own prefix, example:

```
/**
 * @Route("/news")
 * @InheritPrefix("AdminController") <-- an imaginary annotation to show what I mean
 */
class NewsController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="admin_news")
     */
    public function indexAction() {...}

    /**
     * @Route("/list-all", name="admin_news_list-all")
     */
    public function listAllAction() {...}
}
```

The result would be that the URL /admin/news would be routed to the NewsController::indexAction() and /admin/news/list-all would redirect to NewsController::listAllAction()

Then a second class could be created, e.g.

```
/**
 * @Route("/photos")
 * @InheritPrefix("AdminController") <-- an imaginary annotation to show what I mean
 */
class PhotoController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/new", name="admin_photos_new")
     */
    public function newAction() {...}
}
```

Then the url /admin/photos/new would redirect to PhotoController::newAction()

I know about the SonataAdminBundle but wanted to know if there was a way to do this without that bundle.

Comment: Do you really need this? Just replace @Route("/photos") with @Route("/admin/photos") and that's all.

Comment: This is just a simple example, the real example is actually a a lot more complex and may need me to change the root prefix at one point and I'd prefer not having to go through dozens of controllers to change this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify prefixes for a complete RouteCollection. When using annotations, each controller is a collection. But each imported resource is a collection too. This means you can have an `admin` resource import, with the `/admin` prefix and a controller with a `/news` prefix:

```
# app/config/routing.yml
_admin:
    resource: @AdminBundle/Controller
    prefix: /admin
```

```php
// src/AdminBundle/Controller/AdminController.php

// ...
class AdminController
// ...
```

```php
// src/AdminBundle/Controller/PhotoAdminController.php

// ...

/**
 * @Route("/news")
 */
class PhotoAdminController
// ...
```

Comment: ok, I think I know where you're getting at, I'm going to give it a try and probably ask a couple of more questions.

Comment: I haven't found any way of doing so but is there a way to add routes from a separate bundle to the route collection of another? In my example there would be an AdminBundle that the NewsBundle would add routes from certain classes, e.g. NewsAdminController, to the AdminController RouteCollection.